# GWT API Rest Client with CXF

Tags: java, rest, maven, gwt, cxf

First of all, thanks for your time and I hope to find a solution for this issue.

I would like to create an APIRest Client in a WebProject with Google Web toolkit. I am using CXF in order to use my interfaces to get the client.

I use this code to obtain the client in the serviceImplementation class inside a package in the server of GWT project:

```
    List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<Object>();
    providers.add( new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider() );     
    DomainsAPI resource = JAXRSClientFactory.create("http://localhost:9998/api/v1/", DomainsAPI.class, providers);

    WebClient.client(resource).header("X-USER", userKey).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);        
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Response response = resource.getDomains();  
    String hp = response.readEntity(String.class);
    Domain[] dd = mapper.readValue(hp, Domain[].class);
    ...
```

This code is processed but when resource.getDomains() is called, I obtain the typical error with GWT and CXF:

```
    Advertencia: Interceptor for {http://clientAPIRest.shared.us2p.uitu.com/}DomainsAPI has thrown exception, unwinding now
    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No conduit initiator was found for the namespace http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http.

    ....
    Caused by: org.apache.cxf.BusException: No conduit initiator was found for the namespace http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http.
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.ConduitInitiatorManagerImpl.getConduitInitiator(ConduitInitiatorManagerImpl.java:110)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractConduitSelector.getSelectedConduit(AbstractConduitSelector.java:104)
    ....
```

The POM code is here:

```
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I write the version of some relevant packages, others are defined in the parent pom.

I don't know exactly where is the problem. I saw lots of comments about CXF dependencies but no one is the solution I amb looking for.

I hope your help.
Thanks.

------- One update ---------------

I test the client code in a maven project without GWT, and the client works properly.
The code of the client is

```
     DomainsAPI resource = JAXRSClientFactory.create("http://localho...:9998/api/v1/", DomainsAPI.class);

    WebClient.client(resource).header("X-USER", "super_admin_key").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    Response response = resource.getDomains();  
    String hp = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

with only two dependencies in the new Pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>       

</dependencies>
```

---

Project works properly , so the problem is the integration between GWT and CXF, classpath maybe... but I don't know exactly.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the `cxf*.jar`s (for example `cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.1.jar`) being included in the output WAR/application? Somewhere in `target/some_application/WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Yes Igor. They are included in target/app/WEB-INF/lib, but I don't know if should specify in some place where is the path to acces to lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that library cxf-rt-transports-http is not added to yours classpath. I faced with that problem using GWT 2.5.1 and CXF 3.1.0.

I used as fix of this problem some kind of hack: 
simply instantinate any class from cxf-rt-transports-http before creating client.

For example HTTPTransportFactory.class, this would force GWT to add this lib to classpath on runtime.